# Как в C# запустить приложение из своей программы?

Tags: c#

Как в C# запустить приложение из своей программы?

Answer (score 10):

Нужно использовать класс [Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx).

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Example
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process.Start("Notepad.exe");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А как открыть ту-же программу, через ее ярлык на рабочем столе?