# Открытие исполняемого файла по нажатию кнопки,по названию из textbox1

Tags: c#

В программе есть textbox1 и button1.
Помогите сделать так,чтобы когда в textbox1 вводиться название программы,например chrome.exe,то по нажатию button1 эта программа бы открывалась

*Весь следующий код пишется к кнопке*

```
System.Diagnostics.Process Proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
Proc.StartInfo.FileName = <тут должно быть имя файла,но,я предполагаю что тут надо как-то привязать textbox1>;
Proc.Start();
```

Comment: приведите код, как вы сами пытались решить проблему и что не получилось

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как в C# запустить приложение из своей программы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/6223/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b)

Comment: Правильным ответом было:
Proc.StartInfo.FileName = (textBox1.Text);
Спасибо всем,кто пытался помочь!

Answer (score 1):

Вот так:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process Proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
Proc.StartInfo.FileName = textbox1.Text;
Proc.Start();
```

Эта штука не будет работать с программами расположенными по путям не прописанным в Path операционной системы, всякие блокноты, калькуляторы будут работать нормально. Для остальных надо будет указывать полный путь или самому искать exe с таким именем на диске и в FileName присваивать полный путь.

Comment: Не знаю как у Вас,но у меня Visual Studio ругается на текстбокс.
https://imgur.com/a/TRS5PtW

Comment: Я не знаю какое имя у вашего TextBox-а. Указал то, что вы привели в вопросе. Скорее всего у вашего в имени b большая, вот так: textBox1. Посмотрите какое у него имя и укажите правильно. Ну и почитайте немного про C#, у вас недопонимание базовых вещей, так писать программы, к сожалению, не получится :(