# Не запускается приложение после клика по кнопке

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Пытаюсь разобраться почему не запускается приложение после клика по кнопке.

```
private void PB_START_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\\папка\\exe.exe"))
    {
        this.Hide();
        if (ProcessAsUser.Launch(Application.StartupPath + "\\папка\\exe.exe"))
            Application.Exit();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Файл не найден!");
    }
}
```

---

Здесь таки активация запуска процесса как я понял.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
 using System.Diagnostics;

 namespace updater
{
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
{
    public IntPtr hProcess;
    public IntPtr hThread;
    public uint dwProcessId;
    public uint dwThreadId;
}



[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
internal struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
{
    public uint nLength;
    public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
    public bool bInheritHandle;
}


[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct STARTUPINFO
{
    public uint cb;
    public string lpReserved;
    public string lpDesktop;
    public string lpTitle;
    public uint dwX;
    public uint dwY;
    public uint dwXSize;
    public uint dwYSize;
    public uint dwXCountChars;
    public uint dwYCountChars;
    public uint dwFillAttribute;
    public uint dwFlags;
    public short wShowWindow;
    public short cbReserved2;
    public IntPtr lpReserved2;
    public IntPtr hStdInput;
    public IntPtr hStdOutput;
    public IntPtr hStdError;

}

internal enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL
{
    SecurityAnonymous,
    SecurityIdentification,
    SecurityImpersonation,
    SecurityDelegation
}

internal enum TOKEN_TYPE
{
    TokenPrimary = 1,
    TokenImpersonation
}

public class ProcessAsUser
{

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CreateProcessAsUser(
        IntPtr hToken,
        string lpApplicationName,
        string lpCommandLine,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
        bool bInheritHandles,
        uint dwCreationFlags,
        IntPtr lpEnvironment,
        string lpCurrentDirectory,
        ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo,
        out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);


    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DuplicateTokenEx", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool DuplicateTokenEx(
        IntPtr hExistingToken,
        uint dwDesiredAccess,
        ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes,
        Int32 ImpersonationLevel,
        Int32 dwTokenType,
        ref IntPtr phNewToken);


    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool OpenProcessToken(
        IntPtr ProcessHandle,
        UInt32 DesiredAccess,
        ref IntPtr TokenHandle);

    [DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CreateEnvironmentBlock(
            ref IntPtr lpEnvironment,
            IntPtr hToken,
            bool bInherit);


    [DllImport("userenv.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool DestroyEnvironmentBlock(
            IntPtr lpEnvironment);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(
        IntPtr hObject);

    private const short SW_SHOW = 5;
    private const uint TOKEN_QUERY = 0x0008;
    private const uint TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002;
    private const uint TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY = 0x0001;
    private const int GENERIC_ALL_ACCESS = 0x10000000;
    private const int STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 0x00000001;
    private const int STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK = 0x00000040;
    private const uint CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT = 0x00000400;


    private static bool LaunchProcessAsUser(string cmdLine, IntPtr token, IntPtr envBlock)
    {
        bool result = false;


        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saProcess = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES saThread = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
        saProcess.nLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(saProcess);
        saThread.nLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(saThread);

        STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
        si.cb = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(si);


        //if this member is NULL, the new process inherits the desktop 
        //and window station of its parent process. If this member is 
        //an empty string, the process does not inherit the desktop and 
        //window station of its parent process; instead, the system 
        //determines if a new desktop and window station need to be created. 
        //If the impersonated user already has a desktop, the system uses the 
        //existing desktop. 

        si.lpDesktop = @"WinSta0\Default"; //Modify as needed 
        si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW | STARTF_FORCEONFEEDBACK;
        si.wShowWindow = SW_SHOW;
        //Set other si properties as required. 

        result = CreateProcessAsUser(
            token,
            null,
            cmdLine,
            ref saProcess,
            ref saThread,
            false,
            CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT,
            envBlock,
            null,
            ref si,
            out pi);


        if (result == false)
        {
            int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            string message = String.Format("CreateProcessAsUser Error: {0}", error);
            Debug.WriteLine(message);

        }

        return result;
    }


    private static IntPtr GetPrimaryToken(int processId)
    {
        IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr primaryToken = IntPtr.Zero;
        bool retVal = false;
        Process p = null;

        try
        {
            p = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
        }

        catch (ArgumentException)
        {

            string details = String.Format("ProcessID {0} Not Available", processId);
            Debug.WriteLine(details);
            throw;
        }


        //Gets impersonation token 
        retVal = OpenProcessToken(p.Handle, TOKEN_DUPLICATE, ref token);
        if (retVal == true)
        {

            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            sa.nLength = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(sa);

            //Convert the impersonation token into Primary token 
            retVal = DuplicateTokenEx(
                token,
                TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY | TOKEN_DUPLICATE | TOKEN_QUERY,
                ref sa,
                (int)SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityIdentification,
                (int)TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary,
                ref primaryToken);

            //Close the Token that was previously opened. 
            CloseHandle(token);
            if (retVal == false)
            {
                string message = String.Format("DuplicateTokenEx Error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                Debug.WriteLine(message);
            }

        }

        else
        {

            string message = String.Format("OpenProcessToken Error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            Debug.WriteLine(message);

        }

        //We'll Close this token after it is used. 
        return primaryToken;

    }

    private static IntPtr GetEnvironmentBlock(IntPtr token)
    {

        IntPtr envBlock = IntPtr.Zero;
        bool retVal = CreateEnvironmentBlock(ref envBlock, token, false);
        if (retVal == false)
        {

            //Environment Block, things like common paths to My Documents etc. 
            //Will not be created if "false" 
            //It should not adversley affect CreateProcessAsUser. 

            string message = String.Format("CreateEnvironmentBlock Error: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            Debug.WriteLine(message);

        }
        return envBlock;
    }

    public static bool Launch(string appCmdLine /*,int processId*/)
    {

        bool ret = false;

        //Either specify the processID explicitly 
        //Or try to get it from a process owned by the user. 
        //In this case assuming there is only one explorer.exe 

        Process[] ps = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
        int processId = -1;//=processId 
        if (ps.Length > 0)
        {
            processId = ps[0].Id;
        }

        if (processId > 1)
        {
            IntPtr token = GetPrimaryToken(processId);

            if (token != IntPtr.Zero)
            {

                IntPtr envBlock = GetEnvironmentBlock(token);
                ret = LaunchProcessAsUser(appCmdLine, token, envBlock);
                if (envBlock != IntPtr.Zero)
                    DestroyEnvironmentBlock(envBlock);

                CloseHandle(token);
            }

        }
        return ret;
    }

} 
}
```

Comment: Такие вещи отладкой решаются. Поставьте точку останова на строку `if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "\\папка\\exe.exe"))` и далее шагами вперед, проверяя значения переменных.

Comment: Решение найдено здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/6223/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Как в C# запустить приложение из своей программы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/6223/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d1%8b)

Comment: Это шутка такая или как? Там же нет ответа на заданный вопрос...